# using sched_yield to control thread execution

Tags: c++, scheduling

I have 2 threads: vowels and consonants that will "re-print" a user input statement. the vowels thread will print words that start with vowels and consonant thread will print the words that start with consonants ... I am trying to use sched_yield() to make the output in the same order as the user input ... 
so if the user input is: hi all, consonants thread will print hi and vowels will print all, in that order .. but it seems I am missing something, because I am not getting the same order .. could you help ...

```
void *vowels( void *s )
{
    for(int i = 1; i < noOfTokens; i++){
        string str = tokens[i];
        size_t found = str.find_first_of(vowelList);
        if(found == 0){
            printf("vows %s\n", tokens[i]);
        }
        else {
            sched_yield();
      } 
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}


/* the cons thread should print all words starting with a consonant.  */
void *consonants( void *s )
{
    for(int j = 1; j < noOfTokens; j++){
        string str = tokens[j];
        size_t found = str.find_first_of(vowelList);
        if(found != 0){
            printf("cons %s\n", tokens[j]);
        }
        else {
            sched_yield();
      } 
  }
  pthread_exit(0);

}
```

Comment: This will never work without some inter-thread communication. `yield` is a message to the scheduler that basically says "I don't need any more time to run right now, go ahead and give time to any thread you like, including me". Look into using a semaphore or mutex.

Comment: Unless there are more ready-to-run threads than you have cores, your threads will have nothing to yield to, so `sched_yield` won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

As Kenney said, using `yield` alone won't help you to synchronize these two threads. For this you'd have to use mutex or some other synchronization primitive. That being said, I couldn't help but notice that your problem can be elegantly solved with help of `condition variable`. I opted to use `c++11` and `std::thread`, along with `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`.

I simplified your problem a bit, and my goal is to print even and odd integers buy two different threads in the order they are entered (one thread is responsible for even numbers and the other one for odd numbers). One possible solution might be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
unsigned int index = 0;

void ProcessEvenNumbers(void *p_array)
{
    std::vector<int>& buffer(*reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(p_array));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);

    while (index < buffer.size())
    {
        if (buffer[index] % 2 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "thread_1: " << buffer[index] << std::endl;
            ++index;
        }
        else
        {
            cv.wait(lock);
        }
    }
}

void ProcessOddNumbers(void *p_array)
{
    std::vector<int>& buffer(*reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(p_array));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);

    while(index < buffer.size())
    {
        if (buffer[index] % 2 != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "thread_2: " << buffer[index] << std::endl;
            ++index;
        }
        else
        {
            lock.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1));
            lock.lock();
        }
    }

    cv.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> buffer{ 1, 3, 24, 5, 100, -23, -2, -2, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14 };
    std::thread thread_2(ProcessOddNumbers, &buffer);
    std::thread thread_1(ProcessEvenNumbers, &buffer);

    thread_1.join();
    thread_2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The thread that handles even numbers (`ProcessEvenNumbers()`) uses condition variable to block itself when it encounters an odd number. The thread that handles odd numbers (`ProcessOddNumbers()`) uses `notify_one()` to unblock the other thread when it encounters even number, and block itself by attempting to re-lock the mutex (that is at this point already locked by other thread).

`std::this_thread::sleep_for()` is critical as it forces a context switch that allows `thread_1` to lock the mutex after `thread_2` signaled the condition variable.

**P.S.** order in which threads are run is irrelevant.